# Specifying locationURI for new Eclipse toolbar?

Tags: eclipse, menu, eclipse-plugin

I have created a toolbar `my.toolbar` that I would like to add after the "navigate toolbar" containing the: previous annotation, next annotation, back, and forward - buttons.

I have tried the following `locationURIs` (based on info from the Plug-in Spy):

```
locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar?after=navigate"
locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar?after=org.eclipse.ui.workbench.navigate"
locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar?after=toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.workbench.navigate"
```

But either the `my.toolbar` (with my command) does not show up or it shows up BEFORE the navigate toolbar. Any ideas?

Below is my extension point:

```xml
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            allPopups="false"
            locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar?after=navigate">
         <toolbar
               id="my.toolbar">
            <command
                  commandId="my.command"
                  icon="images/img.png"
                  id="my.toolbar"
                  style="push">
            </command>
         </toolbar>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the *Plug-in Menu Spy* to find the `locationURI`.

Just press *Alt+Shift+F2* to trigger the Menu Spy and click a toolbar button. A popup dialog will show all details including the `locationURI`

Comment: For some reason, locationURI is (no longer?) shown in the Menu Spy popup (at least for the main toolbar ...). Tried both Luna and Neon ... :-(